# How to rank records within each group and also checking other variable to assign rank if two records had same rank within the group in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set which basically tells you how many coupons were sent for each retailers, and how many responded, their corresponding response rate for each dealer and for each coupons.

I am looking to rank each coupons within each dealer based on response rate and if two coupons had same response rate, then I need to assign better rank to the coupons which was sent the most

This is the script that  I have tried but it is not ranking properly

```
SELECT 
    DealerCode, Coupon_name, emailsent, responders, responserate,
    RN = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DealerCode, Coupon_name, responserate
                      ORDER BY DealerCode, responserate, emailsent)
FROM 
    table123
```

This is the expected result

```
RetailerCode    Coupon_name emailsent   responders  responserate    RN
----------------------------------------------------------------------
A1                Coupon 1     6              1     0.166666667      1
A1                Coupon 2     10             1     0.1              2
A1                Coupon 7     50             2     0.04             3
A1                Coupon 9     25             1     0.04             4
A2                Coupon 1     28             3     0.10714          2
A2                Coupon 4     12             0     0                3
A2                Coupon 3     1217           131   0.1076           1
A3                Coupon 2     63             10    0.1587           1
A3                Coupon 6     9              1     0.11111          2
A3                Coupon 7     3              0     0                3
A3                Coupon 8     2              0     0                4
A4                Coupon 4     174            22    0.1266782        3
A4                Coupon 3     1118           244   0.2182869        1
A4                Coupon 6     3091           420   0.135877         2
A5                Coupon 3     1227           78    0.06356962       2
A5                Coupon 2     780            50    0.064104         1
A5                Coupon 1     164            6     0.0365866        3
```

Comment: you should also add  a coherent data sample  .. Not only the expcted  result  ..

Comment: updated the dataset...it looks good now i guess

Comment: i don't see  any sample  ..  only the expected  result

Comment: the first 5 columns is the datasample, 6th column is what i am expecting. I tried pasting data from excel but it is pasting as image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your sample  you should only use PARTITION BY DealerCode

```
  SELECT DealerCode, Coupon_name, emailsent, responders, responserate,
   RN = RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY DealerCode
   ORDER BY DealerCode,responserate,emailsent)
  FROM table123
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to `PARTITION BY` the `dealercode` and the `coupon_name` and `ORDER BY` the `responserate` and `emailsent` (assuming that this holds the number a coupon was sent) both descending.

```
SELECT dealercode,
       coupon_name,
       emailsent,
       responders,
       responserate,
       rn = rank() OVER (PARTITION BY dealercode,
                                      coupon_name
                         ORDER BY responserate DESC,
                                  emailsent DESC)
       FROM table123;
```

Comment: It gives me all the ranking as '1'...Column rn is full of '1' :(....yes emailsent is the number of coupons sent

Comment: @mavles: Please provide a demonstration e.g. on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that shows your issue.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number

```
SELECT dealercode,
       coupon_name,
       emailsent,
       responders,
       responserate,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dealercode,
                                      coupon_name
                         ORDER BY responserate DESC,
                                    emailsent desc
                                  ) RN
       FROM table123;
```

Comment: i dont see emailsent here either in order by or in partition by. Please note if the response rate is same then i neeed to assign better ranking to the coupon which was sent the most